# How to reference Item in ListView when there are more than 1 items?

Tags: android, sqlite

Hey guys this is my code:

```
private void populateListView() {

    Cursor cursor = mydb.getAllEvents();

    String[] fromFieldNames = new String[]
            {DBHelper.EVENTS_COLUMN_NAME,DBHelper.EVENTS_COLUMN_CATEGORY};

    int[] toViewIDs = new int[]
            {R.id.event_name, R.id.cat_name};

    SimpleCursorAdapter myCursorAdapter;
    myCursorAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this,R.layout.item_layout,cursor,fromFieldNames,toViewIDs,0);
    final ListView myList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);

    myList.setAdapter(myCursorAdapter);

    myList.setOnClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener(){

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            String selected = myList.getItemAtPosition(position);
        }
    });`
```

As you can see there's more than one item at the position so how do I reference each individually? e.g I only want to reference the name of the event.

Comment: i think the statement ` there's more than one item at the position` is not really accurate! each position will hold 1 item from the Cursor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

myList.getItemAtPosition(position) gets you the "Object" that represents the row at that position. Simply put, that is defined by your CursorAdapter. This is actually a Cursor object and should be casted as follows:

```
Cursor myCursor = (Cursor) myList.getItemAtPosition(position);
```

You then have to get the String from the correct position in the Cursor (which **should** be in whatever order you put it into the adapter):

```
String myDesiredString = myCursor.getString(cursorPos);
```

where cursorPos is an integer that represents the position you wish to get.

For more information, here is an excellent similar question:
[getItemAtPosition() How to get readable data....](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3886617/getitematposition-how-to-get-readable-data-from-the-selected-item-in-a-listvie)

As a side note, I personally prefer using my own adapter which extends BaseAdapter so that I have more control over the data and can even make the adapter itself return the data [such as defining a method like `public String getEventName(int position)`]. However, the simplest solution for this context is what I described above.

Answer (score 0):

having the `cursor` object allows you to get the item using `position` and `moveToPosition()`

try this:

```
cursor.moveToPosition(position);
cursor.getString(1); // OR
cursor.getInt(1);// OR whatever you need.
```

more info [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/Cursor.html#moveToPosition(int))